# Как правильно построить работу с БД, хранящей огромные данные генома человека?

Tags: mysql, sql, big-data, биоинформатика

Таблица генов человеческого генома невелика, всего 60434 записей:

```
CREATE TABLE `genes-g38-201505` (
  `chr` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `left` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `right` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Complement` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `source` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `ENSEMBL` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `gene_version` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `gene_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `gene_source` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `gene_biotypeid` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Таблица повторов человеческого генома, уже хуже - более 5 с половиной миллионов записей:

```
CREATE TABLE `repeats-g38-201505` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `chr` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `left` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `right` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` tinytext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Это - две служебных таблицы. Из них нам, по большому счёту, важны лишь chr - название хромосомы, left и right - левая и правая координата целого гена/повтора или его части (частей может быть несколько, в этом случае одному name соответствует несколько наборов {chr, left, right}) и name - название гена/повтора.

[Все данные для таблиц.](https://gist.github.com/sanmai/7de3bf96489a718189baea99f6e786a1)

Теперь данные экспериментов на тканях онкологических больных. Формат таблицы таков:

```
CREATE TABLE `51k-80-80-ignore-random-noreverse` (
  `chr` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `left` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `right` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UNIQUE KEY `chr_left_right` (`chr`,`left`,`right`),
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

он одинаков для каждого эксперимента. Каждая запись описывает паттерн ДНК, принадлежащий хромосоме chr, с координатами left и right, количеством штук count. Количество записей разное, от 4 до 7 с половиной миллиона на эксперимент. Каждая запись - уникальный набор по координатам {chr, left, right}

И финальная таблица, в которую нужно собрать данные 4х экспериментов:

```
CREATE TABLE `pk47-pk51-gene-repeat` (
  `chr` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `left` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `right` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `count_k51` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `count_p51` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `count_p47` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `count_k47` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `name_left` varchar(29) NOT NULL,
  `name_right` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `pos_name` (`chr`,`left`,`right`,`name_left`,`name_right`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Фактически, всё просто: нужно найти только те паттерны, которые левым краем попадают на ген, а правым - на повтор, посчитать их количество и вывести в сводную таблицу. С запросом вроде бы проблем не возникло, 4 раза повторяю такой запрос, меняя лишь count_k51 на count_p51 и саму таблицу-источник :

```
INSERT INTO `pk47-pk51-gene-repeat` (
      `chr`,`left`, `right`,`count_k51`,`name_left`, `name_right`
)
SELECT 
     a.`chr`, a.`left`, a.`right`, a.`count` as `count_k51`,
     g.`name` as `name_left`, 
     r.`name` as `name_right` 
FROM `
     51k-80-80-ignore-random-noreverse` a, 
     `genes-g38-201505` g,
     `repeats-g38-201505` r 
WHERE
     a.`chr`=g.`chr` and a.`chr`=r.`chr` and 
     a.`left` < g.`right` and a.`left` > g.`left` and 
     a.`right` < r.`right` and a.`right` > r.`left` 
     on duplicate key 
     update 
       `pk47-pk51-gene-repeat`.`count_k51`=a.`count`;
```

В первый запуск on duplicate key можно не использовать. Наверное, можно составить и единственный запрос вместо 4х, но он будет чрезвычайно громоздким, и я пока решил пробовать так.

Разумеется, запрос не выполнился, отвалился по таймауту, который я и так сильно увеличил. `limit 0,1000; limit 1001,2000` и так далее, как я понимаю, использовать бесполезно, поскольку каждый следующий этап сервер всё равно будет проходить предыдущие.
Решил итерировать запросы по `id`, добавляя ограничение `20000*i< a.id <20000*(i+1)` в запрос, но ситуация не улучшилась, видимо, id надо переопределить, либо заставить сервер проводить данную проверку первой.

Как итог, нужны идеи, как можно оптимизировать запрос, перестроить таблицы или поменять подход, чтобы решить эту задачу (не обязательно чистым SQL-запросом, работать с базой из языков программирования я умею). Скажу спасибо и за советы по физическому ускорению сервера: памяти на машине 32Гб, сервер использует мало, может, какие-то переменные подкрутить?

**Update 1.** Привожу результаты EXPLAIN для запроса:

Изначальное состояние:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'g', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '60433', NULL
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'a', 'ref', 'chr_left_right', 'chr_left_right', '4', 'dna_homo_pairs.g.chr', '47216', 'Using index condition'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'r', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '5317291', 'Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)'
```

Добавлены индексы (chr, left, right) по совету @Mike:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'a', 'ALL', 'chr_left_right', NULL, NULL, NULL, '4721638', NULL
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'g', 'ref', 'chr_left_right', 'chr_left_right', '4', 'methyl_base.a.chr', '604', 'Using index condition'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'r', 'ref', 'chr_left_right', 'chr_left_right', '5', 'methyl_base.a.chr', '53172', 'Using index condition'
```

**Update 2**. Заставить mysqld работать в несколько потоков.

Взглянул на загрузку CPU во время запроса. Поскольку сейчас я работаю в монопольном режиме, я один обращаюсь в локальному серверу. **Можно ли как-то заставить mysqld обрабатывать один запрос в несколько потоков?** А то 8 ядер/16 потоков в его распоряжении, а он пользует только один.

Кстати, раскидывание разных таблиц в папки на разных физических жестких дисках даёт, пусть небольшое, но ускорение работы.

**Update 3** На данный момент я программно разбил все исходные таблицы в зависимости от того, какая хромосома и скрипт (точнее, серия скриптов, тоже вызываются программно) сейчас выглядит так ( допустим, обрабатывается 7я хромосома):

```
INSERT INTO `pk47-pk51-gene-repeat` (
      `chr`,`left`, `right`,`count_k51`,`name_left`, `name_right`
)
SELECT 
     "7", a.`left`, a.`right`, a.`count` as `count_k51`,
     g.`name` as `name_left`, 
     r.`name` as `name_right` 
FROM `
     51k-80-80-ignore-random-noreverse-chr7` a, 
     `genes-g38-201505-chr7` g,
     `repeats-g38-201505-chr7` r 
WHERE
     a.`left` < g.`right` and a.`left` > g.`left` and 
     a.`right` < r.`right` and a.`right` > r.`left` 
     on duplicate key 
     update 
       `pk47-pk51-gene-repeat`.`count_k51`=a.`count`;
```

Но особого прогресса не отмечаю.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72761/discussion-on-question-by-viktor-tomilov------).

Comment: Попробуйте использовать InnoDB вместо MyISAM, и [раскачайте буферы](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html) до половины оперативки хотя бы. Вы думаете что у вас работа в процессор упирается, а на самом деле очень может быть что процессор загружен ожиданием новых данных диска.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, ссылки на актуальные дампы данных в сам вопрос. В чате разные ссылки упоминаются, пойди разбери какая для чего.

Comment: @sanmai в чате - единственная ссылка на данные, дважды повторенная: http://sibenzyme.com/files/chr1-for-test.rar

Comment: Отлично, добавил в ваш вопрос [ссылку на копию](https://gist.github.com/sanmai/7de3bf96489a718189baea99f6e786a1/revisions). Как ни крути получает что такую задачу через БД решать - как из пушки по воробьям. Решить можно, но какой ценой...

Comment: @sanmai ответ MIke решает задачу только возможностями БД, и вполне быстро и успешно - как раз адаптировал его и проверил получением ответа с четверть часа назад.

Comment: 45 секунд против четырёх секунд для [программы на Perl](https://pastebin.com/kgjSS44L), не говоря уж про существенно большую сложность самой программы. Так-то решает, конечно, да.

Comment: @sanmai а время на выгрузку данных из таблицы и затем обратно на внесение полученных данных в новую вы учли?

Comment: У вас тут данных на 36 мегабайт. Это секунды. Вы смеётесь? Давайте не будем здесь чат разводить. [Всё сюда дальше.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72761/discussion-on-question-by-viktor-tomilov------)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72851/discussion-between-viktor-tomilov-and-sanmai).

Comment: Хорошие вопросы у вас. Если не будет хватать репы для конкурсов — пишите, выделю. )

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Обычные методы оптимизации, применяемые СУБД обычно берут 1 запись из первой таблицы и ищут по всей второй таблице подходящие записи. При наличии индекса это происходит довольно быстро, за `log2(m)`, но все таки это обращения к десятку страниц индекса ... Ваш запрос при обычном Join должен выполняться в лучшем случае за `O=n*(log2(m)+log2(k))` (Где n,m,k количество записей в 3х таблицах в запросе) (хотя если посмотреть статьи по оптимизации MySQL там вообще выйдет `O=n*log2(m)*log2(k)`)

С другой стороны, ваши данные довольно специфичны (жаль СУБД не способна это оценить). В таблицах genes и repeats лежат не пересекающиеся интервалы, следовательно при сортировке по полю *left* записи оказываются отсортированы и по *right*. В таблицах с паттернами же интервалы временами пересекаются, в итоге при сортировке по *left* поле *right* иногда немного "возвращается назад", но таких ситуаций порядка 8%.

Сравнивать один отсортированный список с отсортированным же списком возможных интервалов можно гораздо проще, идя параллельно по обоим спискам одновременно, сдвигая указатель вперед в том списке, в котором записи еще меньше, чем в другом. Причем так можно проходить параллельно по более чем по 2 спискам одновременно. При этом сложность поиска оказывается `O=n+m+k`.

К сожалению из за того, что список паттернов не может быть одновременно отсортирован и по *left* и по *right* нам иногда надо откатывать указатель в repeats немного назад. В MySQL при работе с курсорами это невозможно, по этой причине я решил запоминать те записи, которые выпали из последовательности возрастающих *right* и при этом могли попасть в интервал предыдущей записи repeats (таких оказалось совсем мало 2k из 438k). Этого можно избежать помня несколько последних записей repeats, но на MySQL это будет слишком громоздко. Сохраненные записи приходится обрабатывать за второй проход, проходя по repeats отсортированной по полю *right*.

На основе вышеизложенного у меня вышла следующая хранимая процедура:

```
create table miss_rows(`left` int not null, `right` int not null,
                       `count` int not null,`name_left` varchar(100) not null);

drop procedure if exists genjoin;
delimiter $$
create procedure genjoin()
begin

 declare endOfData integer default 0;
 declare done int default 0;
 declare cnt int default 0;

 declare g_left int default 0;  -- Переменные для genes
 declare g_right int default 0;
 declare g_name varchar(100);
 declare gen_eof int default 0;  -- Признак конца genes

 declare r_left int default 0;   -- Переменные для repeats
 declare r_right int default 0;
 declare r_Oright int default 0; -- Значение правого конца предыдущей записи
 declare r_name varchar(100);
 declare rep_eof int default 0;  -- Признак конца repeats

 declare t_left int default 0;   -- Переменные рабочей таблицы
 declare t_right int default 0;
 declare t_Oright int default 0; -- Значение правого конца предыдущей записи
 declare t_count int default 0;

 declare gen_cur cursor for
  select `left`,`right`,`name` from genes order by 1,2;
 declare rep_cur cursor for
  select `left`,`right`,`name` from repeats order by 1,2;
 declare data_cur cursor for
  select `left`,`right`,`count` from t47k order by 1,2;

 declare miss_cur cursor for
  select `left`, `right`, `count`, `name_left` from miss_rows order by 2;
 declare rep2_cur cursor for
  select `left`,`right`,`name` from repeats order by 2;


 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET endOfData=1;

 open gen_cur;
 open rep_cur;
 open data_cur;
 truncate table miss_rows;

 row: while done=0 do
    if t_Oright<t_right then set t_Oright=t_right; end if; -- Сохраняем предыдущее значение
   fetch data_cur into t_left, t_right, t_count;
   if endOfData=1 then set done=1,endOfData=0; end if;

   while t_left >= g_right and gen_eof=0 do
     fetch gen_cur into g_left, g_right, g_name;
     if endOfData=1 then set gen_eof=1,endOfData=0; end if;
   end while;

   while t_right >= r_right and rep_eof=0 do
     if r_Oright<r_right then set r_Oright=r_right; end if; -- Сохраняем предыдущее значение
     fetch rep_cur into r_left, r_right, r_name;
     if endOfData=1 then set rep_eof=1,endOfData=0; end if;
   end while;

   if t_left <= g_left or t_left >= g_right then iterate row; end if;
   if t_Oright > t_right then  -- Концы не по порядку, пересечение интервалов !
     if t_right < r_Oright then -- Мы могли попасть в предыдущую запись repeats !
       -- но пропустили ее ...
       insert into miss_rows values(t_left, t_right, t_count,g_name);
     end if;
   end if;
   if t_right <= r_left or t_right>= r_right then iterate row; end if;

   insert into `pk47-pk51-gene-repeat`
    (`left`, `right`, `count_k47`,`name_left`,`name_right`)
    values(t_left, t_right, t_count, g_name, r_name)
    on duplicate key update `count_k47`=t_count;

 end while;
 close gen_cur;
 close rep_cur;
 close data_cur;
 open rep2_cur;
 open miss_cur;
 set r_left=0,r_right=0,rep_eof=0,done=0;
 while done=0 do
   fetch miss_cur into t_left, t_right, t_count, g_name;
   if endOfData=1 then set done=1,endOfData=0; end if;

   while t_right >= r_right and rep_eof=0 do
     fetch rep2_cur into r_left, r_right, r_name;
     if endOfData=1 then set rep_eof=1,endOfData=0; end if;
   end while;

   if t_right > r_left then
     insert into `pk47-pk51-gene-repeat`
      (`left`, `right`, `count_k47`,`name_left`,`name_right`)
      values(t_left, t_right, t_count, g_name, r_name)
      on duplicate key update `count_k47`=t_count;
   end if;
 end while;
end$$
```

Время выполнения данной процедуры на контрольном примере из 6k / 444k / 438k записей, составило 45 секунд ... Правда в контрольном примере не было поля chr, когда оно есть, оно конечно должно так же участвовать в сортировке списков и сравниваться во всех условиях. Таблицы 47, 51 и т.п. стоит обрабатывать за отдельные проходы. Если бы была возможность возвращаться назад, можно было бы попробовать обработать все за один проход. Аналогичный [алгоритм на perl](https://pastebin.com/kgjSS44L), беря данные из отсортированных csv файлов работает 4 секунды...

В связи с тем, что в repeats все таки могут быть пересечения интервалов, все немного сложнее и для получения всех вариантов (коих примерно на 200 записей больше изначального варианта (в 130k записей)) лучше все таки использовать массивы, что бы можно было заглядывать немного вперед. на perl это [выглядит так](https://pastebin.com/D8G6ntU0)

Comment: @Mike Как специалист по perl'у вы можете сказать примерно, скрипт, подобный вашему, сможет обработать файлы любого размера?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Разве что именно "подобный". текущая версия тупо грузит файлы в ОЗУ. с теми файлами, что дали для примера оно занимало 320 Мб. очень большие файлы конечно просто не влезут в память. Но учитывая, что алгоритм рассчитан на один проход, то скрипт можно переделать на подгрузку данных частями (фактически так же как сейчас делает SQL-версия), при этом надо что бы они были заранее отсортированы. так же можно грузить данные не из файлов а из БД, так же дочитывая из курсора по мере надобности

Comment: @Mike почти всё понял в вашем скрипте, хотя perl не знаю, кроме for(0..3) :)

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov `for(0..3)` переводится как `for($_=0; $_<=3; $_++)` А `$_` это специальная "переменная по умолчанию", если переменная конструкцией подразумевается, но не указана, то используется она. В цикле загрузки файлов то же она используется, только там ее имя нигде вообще не написано :) chomp(удаление перевода каретки) и split по умолчанию работают там так же с ней.

Comment: Попробовал, получилось. Пришлось немного переделать под себя, но работает :) Хочу сравнить по скорости со скриптом на perl, переписанным на C++ или Delphi.

Answer (score 14):

Начал с рассмотрения запроса, который приведён в тексте вопроса. Несмотря на годный с виду EXPLAIN PLAN, запрос работает так медленно, будто читает всю таблицу вместо обращений к индексу. Правка индексов мало что меняет.

Потом пришло понимание вот какого момента: при обращении к таблице генов, мы указываем только одну границу для колонки `g.left`, а именно: `a.left > g.left`. Таким образом, мы требуем, чтобы граница `g.left` у гена была меньше, чем граница `a.left` у эксперимента. И всё. А если граница `a.left` у эксперимента имеет большое значение, например 100 миллионов? Ну да, чтобы обработать одну строку таблицы эксперимента, понадобится прочитать почти всю таблицу генов. Так уж устроены индексы, что если нет знака равенства, то дело плохо. Таблица генов – относительно невелика, но данные рассуждения относятся и к работе с весьма большой таблицей повторов: `a.right > r.left`. И это главная проблема запроса.

Предоставленный автором фрагмент реальных данных показал, что для генов и повторов разница между `left` и `right` в одной строке может достигать 1,5 млн и 0,5 млн. Это слишком много, но я всё же попробовал оптимизировать условия запроса, и никакого выигрыша не получил. Почему-то даже наоборот.

Как уже было упомянуто другими участниками, гены, повторы и эксперименты можно рассматривать в качестве диапазонов на оси координат, от `left` до `right`. Однако, это только половина дела :) Можно же и саму ось координат тоже поделить на диапазоны.
Поделив ось на диапазоны, мы можем затем для каждого из этих диапазонов найти все гены и повторы, которые туда попадают хотя бы одним краем.

Пара примерчиков
Пример 1:
Ген с координатами `left`=10, `right`=50.
Ось делится на диапазоны по 100 единиц, т.е. 0-99, 100-199, 200-299, ...
В данном случае ген попадает только на один диапазон: 0-99.
Пример 2:
Ген с координатами `left`=140, `right`=360.
Ось делится на диапазоны так же: 0-99, 100-199, 200-299, 300-399, ...
В данном случае ген попадает в три диапазона: 100-199, 200-299, 300-399. Первый и третий диапазоны ген покрывает частично, а второй (средний) – полностью. 

Зачем нужна эта возня с диапазонами на оси координат?

Чтобы понять, давайте вернёмся к условиям задачи: найти эксперименты, которые левым краем `left` попадают на ген, а правым краем `right` попадают на повтор.

Изначально мы искали попадание на гены и повторы, используя неравенства в условиях проверки, и при этом SQL-сервер просматривал гораздо больше строк в таблицах, чем хотелось бы.

Теперь же, зная в какой диапазон оси координат попадает значение левой границы эксперимента `a.left`, мы могли бы сразу проверить именно этот диапазон на наличие в нём (в диапазоне) каких-либо генов. Аналогично с повторами, только для них проверяем по правой границе `a.right`.

Есть ещё одна тонкость: может оказаться так, что ген лежит в координатах `left`=10, `right`=20, а эксперимент в координатах `left`=25, `right`=45. В таком случае они лежат в одном диапазоне 0-99, но они не удовлетворяют условиям задачи. Получается, что проверив диапазон, мы сделали только предварительную выборку более-менее подходящих генов, но для полной уверенности надо применить условия из первоначального запроса.
В итоге, если ось координат разбить по десяткам тысяч, и пронумеровать диапазоны, деля координату на 10000, то запрос для решения задачи будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
SELECT
    a.`chr`, a.`left`, a.`right`, a.`count` as `count_k51`,
    sg.`name` as `name_left`,
    sr.`name` as `name_right`
FROM
    `51k-80-80-ignore-random-noreverse` a
    INNER JOIN `unwind-genes` g ON  /* гены по диапазонам */
        ( a.`chr` = g.`chr` ) and  /* хромосома */
        ( a.`left` div 10000 = g.`hkey` ) and  /* диапазон */
        ( g.`left` < a.`left` ) and ( a.`left` < g.`right` )  /* точное выполнение условий */
    INNER JOIN `unwind-repeats` r ON  /* повторы по диапазонам */
        ( a.`chr` = r.`chr` ) and  /* хромосома */
        ( a.`right` div 10000 = r.`hkey` ) and  /* диапазон */
        ( r.`left` < a.`right` ) and ( a.`right` < r.`right` )  /* точное выполнение условий */
    INNER JOIN `genes-g38-201505` sg ON
        ( g.`gene_id` = sg.`id` )  /* взять имя гена */
    INNER JOIN `repeats-g38-201505` sr ON
        ( r.`repeat_id` = sr.`id` )  /* взять имя повтора */
```

В данном запросе таблицы `unwind-genes` и `unwind-repeats` содержат сведения обо всех диапазонах оси координат, поделённой на отрезки в 10000 единиц, куда попадают, соответственно гены и повторы.

Прикладываю скрипт на обе таблицы, и на хранимые процедуры для их заполнения.
https://pastebin.com/72Rp6Pfy

Время выполнения на моем компьютере (под виртуальной машиной) на полученном фрагменте реальных данных:

```
CALL `proc_unwind_genes`();  /* ~ 0.25 мс */<br>
CALL `proc_unwind_repeats`();   /* ~ 15 сек. */<br>
INSERT ... SELECT ...; /* ~ 2*15 сек. */<br>
```

Хочу отдельно упомянуть, что вызов хранимых процедур (для формирования промежуточных данных по диапазонам) нужен только однократный. Вызывать их повторно нет нужды до тех пор, пока не изменятся служебные данные по генам/повторам.

Плюсы данного метода решения:
 - высокая скорость
 - чистый SQL, без использования дополнительных инструментов
 - нечувствительность к наличию пересечений по интервалам в таблицах генов и повторов, в том смысле что ничего не "сломается" и никакие данные не будут упущены из рассмотрения
 - если таблицы генов и повторов не меняются, то промежуточные данные не нужно пересчитывать для каждого нового эксперимента - экономия времени обработки для каждого нового эксперимента
Минусы:
 - база увеличивается в размерах из-за хранения промежуточных данных по диапазонам

Возможные пути для дальнейшей оптимизации решения:
 - разбивка оси координат по диапазонам другого размера; при уменьшении размера диапазонов можно получить ускорение в выполнении запроса, но увеличится объём промежуточных данных, их объём может стать в десятки раз больше объёма исходных таблиц
 - можно попробовать в таблицы с промежуточными данными закинуть имена генов и повторов, чтобы избавиться от соединения с исходными таблицами (вместо 5-и таблиц запрос будет обходиться 3-мя)

На всякий случай, оставляю полный скрипт своей тестовой БД
https://pastebin.com/eCviySbB

P.S.:
Признаться, раньше с MySQL дела не имел, работал с данной СУБД впервые на данной задаче.
Благодарю, что дали повод и с MySQL ознакомиться, и поучаствовать в решении интересной реальной задачи :)
И прошу прощения за много буков. Не нашёл, как сделать сворачиваемые куски текста (прятать под спойлер)

Comment: Запрос на postgresql на основе данного решения, https://pastebin.com/5SyFBERB. Время работы 3 секунды !!!

Comment: @Mike, поздравляю! Я тут попробовал тоже одним запросом без вспомогательных таблиц, на MS SQL Server, так 22 сек. вышло. До Вашего варианта с PostgreSQL далековато :)

Comment: ан нет, разогнал таки на MSSQL до 3-4 секунды :) https://pastebin.com/PGzB1aC3

Answer (score 10):

**Данное сообщение является не ответом, а подведением итогов конкурса.**
Кратко поблагодарю всех, кто участвовал ответами, комментариями и участием в чате.
Синтез ответов и непосредственное взаимодействие @Mike и @velial, на мой взгляд, позволило разработать оптимальный вариант решения вопроса. Поэтому я создал дополнительный конкурс и вручил награду за конкурс, таким образом,  обоим.

**Что было до публикации вопроса.**
Удаленный сервер, на который выкладывались тестовые (Пока тестовые. Это не значит, что они ненастоящие, это значит, что их мало :) ) результаты исследования тканей онко-больных, как раковых клеток, так и чистых клеток того же органа (p,k). Предполагалось, что сотрудник, которому необходимо сравнение по определенным параметрам, мог запустить подобное сравнение в виде скрипта, с сохранением результат в таблицу, для которой устанавливался срок жизни в 30 суток (если результаты требовались ещё кому-то срок жизни автоматически увеличивался, либо мог быть определен как вечный вручную). Мы столкнулись с тем, что ряд запросов (самый длинный по времени был выставлен в вопросе) выполняются чрезмерно долго. Хотелось сократить время выполнения сравнения, желательно без использования сторонних программ и скачивания/закачивания данных на сервер.

**Что сделано сейчас, по результатам ответов на вопрос.**
Проведена оптимизация почти всех таблиц. Изменены запросы на их создание и заполнение данными. Многие запросы сравнения стали выполняться приемлемо быстро. Оставшиеся "лимитные" запросы пока заменены на комплексные: частично запросы + частично обработка программой, для этого задействована временно неиспользуемая 16-потоковая машина, куда данные сбрасываются по FibreChannel.

**Что делается, что будет сделано.**
Проводятся испытания использования stored procedures. Но на другой машине, куда были частично перенесены данные, поскольку делать испытания на рабочем сервере, который постоянно включен в систему обмена данных, нецелесообразно.
Заказан новый сервер, где будет установлена PostgreSQL (и, возможно, испытаны другие форматы БД) для оценки целесообразности перехода.

**Кроме того**
Сам узнал много нового в процессе общения и изучения представленных ответов. Возможно, что это - самый ценный результат :)

**Update 2019-06-25**
Шесть месяцев уже как крутится сервер на PostgreSQL. База с момента задания вопроса выросла более, чем в 100 раз. В принципе, нормально: самое длительное обращение сейчас занимает менее 20 секунд (это приемлемо, поскольку сами расчёты иногда занимают несколько суток, а порой и недель). Еще раз спасибо всем! :)

**Update 2023-07-04**
Теперь я имею право опубликовать немного статистики. Благодаря усилиям всех, кто участвовал в решении данного вопроса, не менее 2х тысяч людей получили дополнительные 3-5 лет жизни (возможно, и больше, будем наблюдать), более 200 - получили долгую и, надеюсь, счастливую жизнь. Спасибо вам!

Comment: На postgreSQL какой сейчас алгоритм, с номерами диапазонов, как в ответе velial ? А то я тут обнаружил, что в postgresql есть отдельный тип данных "диапазон" (https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/rangetypes) и на них можно строить GiST индексы. Я не пробовал, что это такое, но судя по описанию оно для поиска по диапазонам может оказаться очень удачным решением

Comment: @Mike ЕМНИП, да, как у velial, с минимальными правками (месяца два не был уже в репозитории). Почитаю ссылку, спасибо

Comment: Круто, что сказать, это не сайтики клепать) Радует информация про дополнительные годы жизни за счет оптимизации, казалось бы, обычной базы.

Answer (score 9):

Классная тема вопроса! Только на чистом SQL такую процедуру смерти-подобно делать. Гораздо проще скрипт (например PHP) накатать - который пусть и дольше, но всё выполнит - не единым INSERT-SELECT-ом, а вставляя по одиночке, или в транзакциях пачками. Так понимаю проблема не в производительности, а в том что выполнить до конца не удаётся в принципе. То лучше есть менять подход.

То есть советую из таблицы `51k-80-80-ignore-random-noreverse` выбирать для каждой её записи сопоставления по таблицам `genes-g38-201505` и `repeats-g38-201505`. Если сопоставление найдено, то проводить `INSERT`.

Лимитировать можно и без скрипта. Для начала - чтобы выбирать по одной записи - таблице `51k-80-80-ignore-random-noreverse` нужно добавить первичный ключ:

```
ALTER TABLE `51k-80-80-ignore-random-noreverse` ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

А дальше вашим же запросом теперь можно брать любой отрезок по таблице `51k-80-80-ignore-random-noreverse`:

```
SELECT 
     a.`chr`, a.`left`, a.`right`, a.`count` as `count_k51`,
     g.`name` as `name_left`, 
     r.`name` as `name_right` 
FROM `
     51k-80-80-ignore-random-noreverse a, 
     `genes-g38-201505` g,
     `repeats-g38-201505` r 
WHERE
     a.id > 3000 and a.id < 4000 and /* <- лимитирование обрабатываемых данных */
     a.`chr`=g.`chr` and a.`chr`=r.`chr` and 
     a.`left` < g.`right` and a.`left` > g.`left` and 
     a.`right` < r.`right` and a.`right` > r.`left`;
```

И не будет такой ситуации как вы написали `limit 0,1000; limit 1001,2000 и так далее, как я понимаю, использовать бесполезно, поскольку каждый следующий этап сервер всё равно будет проходить предыдущие` так как теперь работает индекс `id`.

Второе - нужны правильные индексы специально под запрос:

```
ALTER TABLE `51k-80-80-ignore-random-noreverse` ADD KEY `BASE` (`chr`, `left`, `right`);
ALTER TABLE `genes-g38-201505` ADD KEY `BASE` (`chr`, `left`, `right`);
ALTER TABLE `repeats-g38-201505` ADD KEY `BASE` (`chr`, left`, `right`);
```

Индексы под запрос создавать очень просто - нужно добавить в индексы все столбцы(по одному мульти-индексу на таблицу), которые участвуют в `WHERE` кроме первичного ключа, порядок: от столбца с наименьшим кол-вом вариантов, к наибольшему чтобы оптимально работал BTREE.

Ну и последнее - вы используете SQL для очень нетипичной задачи, последний раз видел когда перемножают таблицы в рабочем коде (делают JOIN не оператором = ) 5 лет назад: подсказать что-то, что попадёт в яблочко сложно, кроме того что бить один "толстый" запрос на выполнение множества более "тонких" запросов. Совсем в яблочко - это проверять совпадения в цикле скрипта, который подключается к SQL - но очевидно нужно уметь сделать и запустить такой скрипт, либо обращаться к фрилансерам.

Comment: Если честно, не увидел в ответе ничего нового: часть я уже использовал и до вопроса, варьируя таблицы, часть - подсказал @Mike.

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov гуд - в таком случае ваш вопрос исчерпан, потому что на SQL тут больше нечего подсказать. Только менять подход писать программу на скриптовом языке, которая подключается к SQL - но это уже далеко вне вопроса. Последнее - обращаю ваше внимание на лимитацию: через `LIMIT` тут разрезать запросы неправильно.