# Можно ли сохранить экземпляр TDictionary целиком, включая хэши?

Tags: delphi, оптимизация, хеширование, словари, биоинформатика

Учитывая, что теперь можно [спокойно выделять большие объемы памяти внутри TMemoryStream](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784534/), я вернулся к идее хранения данных геномных исследований, используемых нами внутри TDictionary в файле для будущего повторного использования. Класс определен так:

```
type
  PosIndex = packed record
     chr, pos:integer;
  end;
  PosIndexData = record
    gname, rname, promoter: string;
    count:array[0..NOfTissues-1] of byte;
  end;

TPosDict = class (TDictionary<PosIndex, PosIndexData>)
 private
   procedure SaveToStream(stream: TStream);
   procedure LoadFromStream(stream: TStream);
 public
   procedure SaveToFile(filename:string);
   procedure LoadFromFile(filename:string);
   procedure LoadFromZip(AFileName, InnerName: string);
   procedure SaveToZip(AFileName, InnerName: string);
end;
```

Предупреждая вопросы и комментарии в стиле "Зачем нужен TDictionary, когда есть базы данных?", сразу скажу: у нас мобильное (не в плане телефона, а в плане, что оно часто запускается где попало) приложение, мы не можем использовать стационарный сервер БД, как коллега в своём вопросе [Как оптимизировать таблицы/запрос в MySQL?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778781/), а работа с файловыми БД с нашими объёмами данных, увы, крайне медленна. А вот с TDictionary поиск происходит пусть не мгновенно, но для нас вполне подходяще по времени.

Запись в поток (этот метод затем используют и SaveToFile и SaveToZip) происходит так:

```
procedure TPosDict.SaveToStream(stream: TStream);
var
  writer: TWriter;
  ps:PosIndex;
  pid:PosIndexData;
  l:integer;
begin
  writer := TWriter.Create(stream, 4096);
  l:=sizeof(pid.count);
  try
    writer.WriteListBegin;
    for ps in Self.Keys do
      begin
        pid:=Items[ps];
        writer.WriteInteger(ps.chr);
        writer.WriteInteger(ps.pos);
        writer.WriteString(pid.gname);
        writer.WriteString(pid.rname);
        writer.WriteString(pid.promoter);
        writer.Write(pid.count,l);
      end;
    writer.WriteListEnd;
  finally
    writer.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Метод быстр, гигабайтные данные сохраняются быстро даже в ZIP-файл. А вот считывание из файла крайне медленно из-за того, что данные добавляются во вновь созданный TDictionary, происходит хэширование и проверка на уникальность:

```
procedure TPosDict.LoadFromStream(stream: TStream);
var
  reader: TReader;
  ps:PosIndex;
  pid:PosIndexData;
  l:integer;

begin
  Clear;
  l:=sizeof(pid.count);
  reader := TReader.Create(stream, 9192);
  try
    reader.ReadListBegin;
    while not reader.EndOfList do
    begin
       ps.chr:=reader.ReadInteger;
       ps.pos:=reader.ReadInteger;
       pid.gname:=reader.ReadString;
       pid.rname:=reader.ReadString;
       pid.promoter:=reader.ReadString;
       reader.Read(pid.count,l);
       Add(ps,pid); // вот это всё тормозит!!!
    end;
    reader.ReadListEnd;
  finally
    reader.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Избежать этого, как я понимаю, нельзя. Но ведь это уже было сделано, когда объект существовал ранее, все хэши уже были созданы и работали. Появилась идея: можно ли при сохранении TDictionary как-то сохранить объект целиком, включая хэши, а затем так же восстановить из файла, чтобы не тратилось время на перехэширование. Ну, или другие идеи, как убрать бутылочное горло при восстановлении данных.

Comment: У TDictionary  есть свойство Размер [capacity] (зарезервированное число объектов). Когда реальное число объектов превышает половину зарезервированного, то происходит резкое увеличение параметра Размер и перехэширование всех объектов под новый размер. Так что пробуйте сразу поставить Размер побольше (в 2-3 раза больше реального числа объектов). Отпишитесь о результате?

Comment: Можно, если Ваша установка Delphi включает в себя исходные коды. Либо модифицируем имеющиеся исходники, либо копируем из них код класса TDictionary<,> под своим именем, затем меняем видимость приватных полей на "protected", и благодаря наследованию получаем возможность аккуратненько сериализовать FCount, Length(FItems), FItems, FGrowThreshold. Это будет вариант костыльный, но наверное самый быстрый :) Минус - когда в новых версиях Delphi стандартный код реализации обновится, ваш останется старым. Либо синхронизируем "вручную", либо забиваем. Можно ещё поглядеть на сторонние библиотеки

Comment: @VladChapl Спасибо, попробую. Отпишусь затем.

Comment: @velial Спасибо за подсказку, попробую сделать свой класс, скопировав.

Comment: @VladChapl Снимаю шляпу и предлагаю ответить, чтобы получить законные плюшки. Я ожидал 7% прироста, ну, 15%, но чтобы скорость выросла в десятки раз!!!

Comment: @VladChapl Есть, правда, и небольшой подводный камень: SetCapacitty - приватный метод, и только из конструктора я могу, не переписывая код TDictionary, задать размер. И нельзя вызывать Clear :) Но это уже мелочи :)

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Ну, это просто: определите классовый метод и переменную класса и вызывайте перед конструктором.  В ZIP-файле храните файл, хранящий информацию о библиотеках, в нём хранящихся. Загружайте её и затем передавайте уже точное количество сохраненных элементов в конструктор.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Спасибо, буду изучать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Особенность TDictionary в том, что когда заканчивается ёмкость под хэши, он увеличивает размер и в этот момент происходит перехэширование всей имеющийся (на данный момент) коллекции. Поэтому если заранее примерно известен размер коллекции, то этот размер умноженный на 2-3 можно поставить в capacity.

Comment: В принципе, при желании, можно TDictionary переписать под себя, изменив принцип увеличения памяти. Но, с другой стороны, если выставления Capacity в размер решает все проблем, то зачем? :)