# Вопрос о postgressql + C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

Использую базу данных postgres, в ней 10 таблиц и в каждой около миллиона записей. Все таблицы связаны с вызовами и имеют уникальный md5. И я пишу сейчас клиентское приложение на C# в котором нужно будет обрабатывать данные за год или несколько лет. Джойнить чтобы агрегировать таблицы и выгружать данные запросом очень долго и непроизводительно. Подскажите как поступить мне? Я сейчас учусь и может быть вы меня на правильные мысли наведете....хелп)) Вообще сейчас думал реплику на каждого клиента сделать , но сомневаюсь, что это правильный подход...))

Comment: В большинстве случаев правильно оптимизированный запрос на оптимизированной БД выполнит работу гораздо быстрее, чем стягивание информации в внешнее приложение и обработку ее там. Каждое решение строится исходя из конкретной задачи, со знанием всех нюансов предметной области. В вашем вопросе только общие фразы на основе которых ничего сказать нельзя

Comment: Запрос самый обычный просто по md5 агрегируются все 10 таблиц за указанный период .. На клиенте необходимо сделать анализ этих данных , статистику вызовов , в самой СУБД я не знаю как это можно сделать, вообще когда запрос выполняется оперативка на клиенте полностью забивается.... очень не оптимальный выход с запросом.. а как мне еще обработать эти данные не знаю ... может есть возможность выгружать сразу в файл

Comment: Вот, посмотрите пример того как задавать вопрос так, что бы получить на него ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778781/194569 И кстати это пока единственный известный мне случай, когда вне БД обработка действительно оправдана (и то не факт, на postrgesql можно и в БД)

Comment: И кстати очень может быть, что тот подход с загрузкой и параллельным движением по отсортированным (в вашим случае по md5) данным в вашем случае так же подходит.